# How to block access to my account password(accounts&sync) from other applications?

Tags: android

```
Textview t1=(Textview) findViewById(R.id.tv);
AccountManager acM=AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accs=acM.getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accs) 
        {
             t1.setText(t1.getText() + "\n\n\n" + "Name :" + account.name + "\n"+ "Type :" 
             + account.type + "\nPassword :" + acM.getPassword(account);
        }
```

I'm accessing the password from test application. I want to not access the other applications to my account password. Example I'm not access the facebook account password or twitter password ?

Comment: You can edit questions on SO, so you don't have to post a new one just to clarify. Did you install your own account provider for a custom account type or are you trying this with default account types on the phone?

Comment: sorry. my account type is com.app.mobile.account

example code:
`Account account = new Account(user, "com.app.mobile.account");
   AccountManager aManager = AccountManager.get(mContext);
   
if(aManager.addAccountExplicitly(account,pass, null)) {
   result = new Bundle();
   result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
   result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
   setAccountAuthenticatorResult(result);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only an app that has the same UID as the account provider can access the password. This typically means running within the same app and process (unless you are using `sharedUid`):

> This method requires the caller to hold the permission
>   AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS and to have the same UID as the account's
>   authenticator.

See the reference for more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getPassword(android.accounts.Account)

Comment: An example of what? If both of the snippets you posted above are running in the same app, you will be able to access the password. If you create a new app, and call `getPassword()` from it, you will get an exception, and won't be able to get the password.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest.
I'm trying another application and access the password with `getPassword()` without exception.

I want to "setauthtoken" example.Would it be possible ?
(BTW, sorry I can some speak English)

Comment: This should only work if the other app has the same UID. Not sure what you mean by 'setauthtoken example', but the same restriction holds for  `setAuthToken()` as well: 'the caller to hold the permission AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS and to have the same UID as the account's authenticator'

Comment: [look this image](http://e1211.hizliresim.com/13/u/g9c2l.png)

my application permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />

Comment: I get the picture, but if you can get the password you are either running with the same UID, or your Android version has a serious bug. Make sure you are running in a separate app with a different UID, and maybe try on another device or emulator version.

Comment: thank you very much Nikolay! I'm try coding the test application in the another computer. And tested phones. It's not see my account password. But I'm accessing the emulator. I think for coding the same computer. Thank you very much for your interest. have a nice day!